# How can I use AddHours and AddMinutes for add a time in a DateTime variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'll create a form where the users must enter a date and time. In the database I'll merge the date and the time in one column. How could I do this with ASP.NET MVC and C#?

**Info:** Below you could find my HTML code

```html
<form action="~/admin/NieuweCreateActiviteit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">

        <label class="control-label col-md-2 required" for="NieuwActiviteit_StartPeriode">Aanvang datum</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="NieuwActiviteit_StartPeriode" name="NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode" type="date" class="form-control text-box single-line col-md-6" required data-val="true" data-val-date="Dit veld moet een geldige datum bevatten." data-val-required="Dit veld is vereist." value="">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                <label class="control-label col-md-6 required">Uur</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="time" class="form-control" required data-val-required="Dit veld is vereist." name="BeginUur" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

In the controller receive the date *(property name `NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode`<sup>1</sup>)* and the time *(property name `BeginUur`)* as separated properties.

So my solution was to split the time on the colon *(`:`)* and use the methodes `AddHours` and `AddMinutes` for add the time for the property `StartPeriode`.

But it don't work. If I place an breakpoint on the marked line in code below, the variables `tempstartuur`and `tempstartmin` are oké, but if I step to the next line, the hours are not added to the property `StartPeriode`.

Here is the code of my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NieuweCreateActiviteit(CreateActiviteitViewModel a)
{
    int tempstartuur, tempstartmin;

    if (int.TryParse(a.BeginUur.Split(':')[0], out tempstartuur) && int.TryParse(a.BeginUur.Split(':')[1], out tempstartmin))
    {
        a.NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode.AddHours(tempstartuur);  // breakpoint
        a.NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode.AddMinutes(tempstartmin);
    }
    else
    {
        AddErrors(new IdentityResult("Start uur is geen uur"));
        return View(a);
    }

    // insert in database
    return View();
}
```

**Info:** the view model

```
public class CreateActiviteitViewModel
{
    public Activiteit NieuwActiviteit { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFoto { get; set; }
    public string Submit { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Beschrijving { get; set; }
    public string BeginUur { get; set; }
    public string EindUur { get; set; }
}

public class Activiteit
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Gebuiker { get; set; }
    public string GebuikerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartPeriode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EindPeriode { get; set; }
    public bool Verwijderd { get; set; }
    public bool Opgelost { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Aanwezigen { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }
    public virtual Straat Straat { get; set; }
    public int StraatID { get; set; }
    public string Huisnummer { get; set; }
    public string Organisator { get; set; }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

<sub><sup>1</sup> Sorry, but I'm programming in Dutch... If you got problems with the translation you could ask me in comments.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AddHours` and `AddMinutes` do not modify the instance on which you are calling them, they return a new value. So:

```
a.NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode = a.NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode.AddHours(tempstartuur);
a.NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode = a.NieuwActiviteit.StartPeriode.AddMinutes(tempstartmin);
```

Quote form the [`documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours(v=vs.110).aspx) of the AddHours method:

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of hours to the value of this instance.